# Remap keyboard on the Linux console

Tags: linux, console, keyboard-layout

I'm using Debian and I want to remap my keyboard because it has some problem. I googled and found `xmodmap`. But it doesn't work in graphicless mode, like tty1.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/194202/remapping-keys-system-wide-in-linux-not-just-in-x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linux uses two independent keyboard mappings. One for the graphical mode X and one for the console.

You usually change the first one with `setxkbmap` (or `xmodmap`) and the second one with `loadkeys`. All those tool have a fine manpage.

For `loadkeys` you can find the existing keymaps under `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps`.
The description of those files is available in `man 5 keymaps`.

Comment: [Detailed guide](https://superuser.com/a/290149/162797)

Comment: The 'Detailed guide' in the comment above, doesn't properly show how to make changes permanent. In that same thread, I have an answer for Ubuntu (22.04):
https://superuser.com/questions/290115/how-to-change-console-keymap-in-linux/1813134#1813134 I am pretty sure it works for Debian too.