# How to remap characters like in vim but in the entire OS?

Tags: vim, kde, keyboard

In my `vim` instead using <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to moving I use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+(<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>) (like in a game but enabling it with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>) and I love it, please don't try to convince me that is bad idea, it is not the case.

In fact, as far as I know there is no way to map <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> in `vim`, what I do is mapping those Greek like characters that happens when you press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+(<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>): łæßð.

So, I feel this way of replacing the arrows is very comfortable for my fingers and I'd really love to be able to use it everywhere not only in `vim`, I've been reading how to remap keys in Linux (I use Manjaro) but it looks like you can only map one key code to another, and what I want to do is map characters (łæßð) to the key codes of the arrows.

Someone know how to do that?

From my `.vimrc`:

```
"movement with a,d,w,s
noremap æ <left>
noremap ð <right>
noremap ß <down>
noremap ł <up>
inoremap æ <left>
inoremap ð <right>
inoremap ß <down>
inoremap ł <up>
```

Distribution: Manjaro (Kernel: 5.6.12-1-MANJARO)
Desktop environment: KDE Plasma

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! We might need more information to help you out. Which Linux distribution and which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: already updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 38 = a A a A Left'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 40 = d D d D Right'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 25 = w W w W Up'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 39 = s S s S Down'
```

Write those lines in any graphical environment startup script.

---

#### Detailled answer

One can remap keyboard events using the [`xmodmap`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap#Installation) command. As an exemple if you want to remap <kbd>Altr Gr</kbd> +  <kbd>a</kbd>  to the left arrow, use this command:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 38 = a A a A Left'
```

You can find the keycode of a specific key using the `xev` command: when pressing a key, the terminal will output information including the keycode . You can use the following command from the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_input#Identifying_keycodes_in_Xorg) to output only the relevant information:

```
xev | awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8 }'
```

The five parameters at the right of the equal signal correspond to the modifiers:

```
                               ---> Caps Lock + a = A
                               |
                           ------> Shift + a = A
                           |   |
xmodmap -e 'keycode 38 = a A a A Left' --> Alt. Gr + a = Left 
                         |   |
                         -----> a = a
                             |
                             ----> Ctrl. + a = a
```

In order to run those lines at KDE startup you can add an desktop entry in your `~/.config/autostart/` folder. You need two files: one containing the `xmodmap` settings and one for the startupt desktop entry. Let us write the mapping settings in `~/.config/xmodmap/xmodmaprc`:

```
keycode 38 = a A a A Left
keycode 40 = d D d D Right
keycode 25 = w W w W Up
keycode 39 = s S s S Down
```

And here is an example of a desktop entry file `~/.config/autostart/xmodmap.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name[en_US]=Xmodmap
Comment[en_US]=xmodmap ~/.config/xmodmap/xmodmaprc
Exec=/usr/bin/xmodmap ~/.config/xmodmap/xmodmaprc
Icon=application-default-icon
X-KDE-Autostart-enabled=true
Type=Application
```

I don't have any desktop environment running on my system to try this out but it should be working.

---

#### Notes

1. The `xmodmap` method only works in a graphical environment. This mapping won't work on the Linux console (`tty`). See [Remap keyboard on the Linux console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177024/).
2. Keep in mind that the keyboard is reset at each layout change. This method is only recommended for one-layout configuration.
3. If you did something wrong with `xmodmap` you can erase all settings using `setxkbmap -option`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xmodmap or xkbcomp. There are many examples in the Internet how to make it work. Excuse me, but I do not see any sense in copy/paste method.